# Does Solr support search operators?

Tags: php, solr, solr4

Does Solr support search operators like Google ("only this phrase", -whithout this etc)?
If yes, how enable it?

I found info about query [parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser). It seems what I realy need, but it related to url. Or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you already found an answer but for the sake of completeness:

Well, it does.

Solr ist based on Lucene so most of the "Lucene Query Language" can be used in the q= parameter of your query.

This page helped me a lot:
http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html

Answer (score 0):

Edisxmax parser will allow you to set up this kind of query. As for the name, that is up to you.

Phrase searches can be executed by putting the query in quotes. If you want a document that does not have a term, than prepend a minus to it, this should alsow ork for a phrase. If you need the document to have the term, put a plus in front of it.

from the Manual https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax:


*When dealing with queries there are 3 types of "clauses" that Lucene knows about: mandatory, prohibited, and 'optional' (aka: "SHOULD") By default all words or phrases         specified in the "q" param are treated as "optional" clauses unless they are preceeded by a "+" or a "-". When dealing with these "optional" clauses, the "mm" option makes it possible to say that a certain minimum number of those clauses must match (mm). Specifying this minimum number can be done in complex ways, equating to ideas like...*

Comment: Sorry, I can't undested how enable and configure this. Please, could you please explane?